# Javascript function that restricts numeric functions but allow alphanumeric values

Tags: javascript, regex

i am stuck in a problem...This is my code which restricts special characters but i want a logic which will restricts special characters,numerics but allow alphanumeric values...
for eg:

- valid   : a1,4r,aa.
- invalid : w@,12,@!.

  function check(e)

{

```
var keynum;
var keychar;
var numcheck;
if(window.event) // IE
{
    keynum = event.keyCode;
}
else if(e.which) // netscape/Firefox/opera
{
    keynum = e.which;
}

//condition for backspace(8) Key
if(keynum != 8)
{
    keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
    numcheck = /[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*/;
    return numcheck.test(keychar);
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

}

```
    User id : <input type="text" id="txtname" name="txtname" onkeypress="return check(event)"/>
```

Comment: A simple [regular expression](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml) should be enough.

Comment: "Alphanumeric" means alphabetic + numeric characters, as explained in the [wiki](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric). As such, what do you mean by "restrict numerics", but "allow alphanumerics"?

Comment: Hartley... i want a1,4r,aa to be allowed but should not allow w@,12,@!.

Comment: check the link i have shared @chetanPotdar

Comment: So digits are okay _if_ they are together with letters, but not a "word" containing only digits?

Comment: Similar question is already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388996/regex-for-javascript-to-allow-only-alphanumeric hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would satisfy your need.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

This would restrict only numbers such as 12, 13, etc., would now allow any special character, and as required, would allow words containing alphabets and numbers both such as asd12, 12asd12, 12asd, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha numeric validation from SO itself :

```
var reg_password1 = 'tes123';
var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;

var result = letters.test(reg_password1);

alert(result);
```

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532982/jquery-alphanumeric-validation)

[Fiddle not by me](http://jsfiddle.net/DBEfG/1/)

Comment: it allows numeric only inputs also

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the regex you need :

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

It matches zero or more alphanumeric characters followed by atleast one letter followed by zero or more alphanumeric characters.

So it allows `aa` and `0r`

and does not allow `99` or sequence containing non-alphanumeric characters.

Your question says **only alphanumeric characters are allowed.** Your example says **aa.** should be allowed. If so, use :

```
^[A-Za-z0-9.]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9.]*$
```

It allows `.` along with at least one letter such as **.aa** and **aa.**

Check it like this :

```
numcheck.test(inputString);
```

where `inputString` is the input like `a23`, `we` and `.aa` which are matched or `12` and `k@` which are not matched

`numcheck` is `/[A-Za-z0-9.]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9.]*/`

Comment: am sorry, i wanted to update my answer but by mistake edited your answer, and do not know how to undo edit.

Comment: sorry but its not working...its not allowing me to enter thye numbers...eg.a1..

Comment: @chetanPotdar check well. It allows `a1`

Comment: @chetanPotdar do you want to allow special characters along with letters?

Comment: No naveed it is not allowing me...i have edited my whole code...plz have a luk on it..

Comment: i dont want special chars

Comment: @chetanPotdar check the new regex. If you want to allow `.` also, use that.

Comment: @chetanPotdar if it worked pls accept the answer. Otherwise pls make your requirement clear.

Comment: why my code is not working???

Comment: @chetanPotdar Are you checking each character in  the input separately? Check the whole string against the regex.

Comment: i m nt getting u naveed...cn u correct the mistakes in my code plz

Comment: how to chk the whole string???